# How can I invite facebook friends to install and use my APP with my custom UI?

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to invite facebook friends to install and use my iOS APP with my custom UI.I read the App Link file on facebook but I can't find how to build my UI to invite friends, can anyone help me?

Comment: You're asking to broad a question here. Firstly no one knows what your UI is going to look like and also you need to show us what you've attempted to get specific answers to your questions. At the moment it just sounds like you want someone to code a complete solution I'm afraid

Comment: What is possible is explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_104376946653191